# nginx sub domains reverse proxy with node.js app

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have 3 Node.js app. Client, Admin and API. I also have sub domains: example.com, admin.example.com and api.example.com.
I also have nginx config but it not works (in my opinion)
when I enter api.example.com, it loads example.com's content but when I write sub domain with port, then it works: api.example.com:8081

in client, I'm using angular.js and maybe here is problem, but I don't think so...

this is my nginx conf: /etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/default:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Your rewrite rules seem to suggest that you actually have more `server` blocks in your configuration.

Comment: does anyone have answer? I need help :/

Comment: Do you have other `server` blocks in your configuration? If so, please add them to your question.

Comment: no, I have only 3 server block

Comment: In that case, I don't understand the rewrite rules, they seem to be forwarding all requests to HTTPS, but I don't see any HTTPS server setups.

Comment: Yeah. Remove all your rewrite rules if you don't have any other server blocks